# Are there time series models for weighted data?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, arima, weights, weighted-data

Let's say I have the following time series:

- Weekly data spanning a few years;
- The dependent variable is the proportion of items that pass x. On average, that proportion is around 80%. The number of items is normally around 1000, but some weeks have only 100 items or so.

```
time | items | passed | prop
----------------------------
   1 |  1100 |    900 |  .82
   2 |  1000 |    910 |  .91
   3 |  1010 |    920 |  .91
   4 |   105 |     91 |  .87
```

I want to model and ultimately forecast this proportion. (The dependent variable should be the proportion to avoid out-of-range predictions and for normalization.) However, I would like the model to take into account the number of items per week such that weeks with, say, 900-1100 items have more impact than unusual weeks with only around 100 items. **Does such a time series model exist that can take (analytic) weights into account?** The weight in my case would be the number of items (or some function thereof).

NB: I am aware of the fact that modeling a proportion may require a link function or a transformation.

*There is a related question that has a different focus (and no answers since it was posted in 2017)*: [Does there exist a variant of ARIMA allowing for weighted samples?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/312752/27276)

Comment: What about a binomial/logistic model with time correlation? see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13172/logistic-regression-for-time-series?rq=1  and search this site!

Comment: Ah, thanks, I'll look into these. If someone has related examples (e.g., textbook/blog), I would appreciate any hints. And I'll search this site again!!